# self.class_eval <<DEF ... DEF

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand this function.

What I can see is an attribute and type are passed to the `opal`() method.

Then `type_name` takes its value from `type` as long as `type` is a `Symbol` or `String`. Otherwise, the `name` method is called on `type`. I imagine the `name` method is similar to the `class` method to get the class of the `type` argument.

After `self.class_eval` I'm kind of lost but my guess is this is defining maybe a block of code to be added to the class referenced by `self`.

How this works I'm not sure though.

**Would appreciate if someone could explain what's going on after `self.class_eval << DEF`.**

```
    def opal(attr, type)
      self.ds "#{attr}_id"
      type_name = (type.is_a?(Symbol) || type.is_a?(String)) ? type : type.name
      self.class_eval <<DEF
  def #{attr}
    if defined?(@#{attr})
      @#{attr}
    else 
      @#{attr} = if self.#{attr}_id
          #{type_name}.get(self.#{attr}_id)
        else
          nil
        end
    end
  end

  def #{attr}=(value)
    self.#{attr}_id = value.key
    @#{attr} = value
  end
DEF
    end
```

Comment: why was this down voted? It's programming related and the question does not appear to be unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything between `<<DEF` and `DEF` is just a string and the `#{ ... }`s work on that string like any other.

`class_eval` will cause the interpreter to run on the string in the context of the module.

So, if you know what `attr` and `type` are then you can work out what code is being run to add methods to the class.

Lets say `attr` is `"foo"` and `type` is `"Bazzle"`. The code being run would be:

```
def foo
  if defined?(@foo)
    @foo
  else 
    @foo = if self.foo_id
      Bazzle.get(self.foo_id)
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end

def foo=(value)
  self.foo_id = value.key
  @foo = value
end
```

Comment: You say "class_eval will cause the interpreter to run on the string in the context of the module". So if I say self.class_eval "def bar end", the interpreter will add a "bar" method to the class?

Comment: Yes. If you did that and there was already a `bar` method in the class it would be overridden.

Answer (score 3):

To make it easy to understand, let's suppose the value of 'attr' is 'foo', here's what it looks like now:

```
self.class_eval <<DEF
  def foo
    if defined?(@foo) # Return the value of attr if it's defined
      @foo
    else 
      @foo = if self.foo_id
          #{type_name}.get(self.foo_id)
        else
          nil
        end
    end
  end

  def foo=(value) # Define setter
    self.foo_id = value.key
    @foo = value
  end
DEF
```

So it's just defining some getter and setter methods for @foo, and evaluating it at the class level.